# How can I migrate a "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" 1.0 app's local storage to "@capacitor/core" 4.0+ on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage, capacitor

I have an Ionic 3 app on Google Play Store that uses version "^1.1.16" of "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview". The app previously directly interacted with local storage and stored JSON data in key-value pairs. No plugin was used for storage. Since it used this version of the plugin, [I believe the local storage data was stored in the "file:///" origin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/1137#issuecomment-824881641).

I have created an updated version of the app that runs on Ionic 6 and "@capacitor/core": "4.3.0". I believe "http" is the new origin used. Since its local storage is in a different location, it means that a user on the old version that is updating to the new version of the app will lose their stored data. How can I migrate the old data to ensure that the user does not lose their data? Its a very old app so this new version is basically a rewrite to make sure it can meet Google Play Store requirements.

I have tried changing the "capacitor.config.json" server property to "file" but this did not work as it was blocked in Ionic Capacitor (https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/3854):

```json
    "server": {
         "androidScheme": "file"
    }
```

I have looked at some existing plugins that appear to do migrations however I don't think any of them will work in my scenario. This is because I am migrating from a very old version of Cordova to Capacitor + I am not using any DBs/storage plugins and just working directly with Local Storage. Existing plugin options I looked at but decided against:

1. [migrate-cordova-localstorage](https://github.com/Lucas-Feichtinger/migrate-cordova-localstorage)
2. [cordova-plugin-ionic-migrate-storage](https://github.com/pointmanhq/cordova-plugin-ionic-migrate-storage)
3. [Preferences configure options](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/preferences#configureoptions)